# Hosted website unavailable after uninstalling local copy

Tags: apache2, lamp, hosts

I attempted to install my hosted Wordpress site on my 12.04 desktop following the Ubuntu Lamp guide, then after being unable to get it running properly attempted to uninstall it using suggestions in the Ubuntu forum and Synaptic.

When I attempt to access the hosted site with Firefox or Chrome, I get `can't establish a connection to the server at www.interfaithsheltersf.org`

I get a similar response trying to access `localhost`.

I can connect to the hosted site on my wife's computer.

I only know a few basic terminal commands, but following one suggestion to see whether all traces of the installation were removed, I got this:

```
gaines@gaines:/$ dpkg --get-selections | grep apache
libapache2-mod-php5             deinstall

gaines@gaines:/$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
libmysqlclient18                deinstall
mysql-server-5.5                deinstall
php5-mysql                      deinstall
```

Any suggestions as to what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

After retracing my steps to install Lamp and my Wordpress site locally, I realized that one of the sites I used had me edit etc/hosts to have localhost and the hosted url point to the local copy of my WP site.

As I had deleted that local site, hosts could only tell me that it couldn't connect.  Removing the pointers from hosts allowed me to access the hosted site.